# Google Author information in search results still havent displayed my details in search results

Tags: google-search, google-plus-one

I followed the following instructions but still not clear whether i had completely understood it.

http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=1408986
http://www.labnol.org/internet/author-profile-in-google/19775/

I did the above last week and i did not find my picture in google search result.

First i added google + link in certain web pages and in my google profile i added those pages which had google + anchor link with rel=author tag.

After updating i used the following to verify.

http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?url=http%3A%2F%2Fvikku.info%2Fcodesnippets%2Fphp%2F&view=

You can see that my pic is appearing at the right. here is a screen shot.

[image]

so, what am i missing? why it is not in the search result. The author of labnol.org said it will take 3 days for my profile photo link to appear... ?

Google has stated the following

Note that there is no guarantee that a Rich Snippet will be shown for this page on actual search results. For more details, see the FAQ( http://knol.google.com/k/google-rich-snippets-tips-and-tricks#Frequently_Asked_Questions ).

Fingers crossed. Thoughtful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've pretty much answered your own question by posting the quote from Google that states that using a rich snippet does not mean Google will use it in their search results. As with anything SEO and Google related, if you've implemented the rich snippet then all you can do is continue to add quality content and attract new links. Eventually, if you're content is good enough, you'll meet whatever criteria Google has set forth to use the rich snippet in their search results (in other words you've gotten enough "link juice").